# cs50w commerce project : IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-errors

I'm working on cs50w's commerce project, trying to create a new listing, but I keep getting this error:

```
IntegrityError at /new
UNIQUE constraint failed: auctions_listings.user_id
```

Here are my models for user and listing:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    #def __str__(self):
        #return f"{self.username}"

class Listings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.TextField()
    #starting_bid = models.FloatField(validators = [MinValueValidator(1)])
    img = models.URLField(blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner", primary_key=True)
```

This is my view for new listing:

```
def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request, "auctions/new_listing.html", {
                "message": "Try logging in first"
            })
        user = request.user

######################################################
        for u in User.objects.all():
            print(f" UID  = =  {u.pk} | Name = = {u}")
######################################################

        title = request.POST["title"]
        img = request.POST["image"]
        category = request.POST["category"]
        #starting_bid = request.POST["starting_bid"]
        description = request.POST["description"]

        listing = Listings.objects.create(
            user = user,
            title = title,
            img = img,
            category = category, 
            #starting_bid = starting_bid,
            desc = description
        )

        if listing is not None:
            listing.save()

        return redirect("index")

    return render(request, "auctions/new_listing.html")
```

And the form for creating a new listing:

```
<form action="{% url 'new' %}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" style="width: 50%; margin: auto;">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title: </label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" autofocus required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image URL: </label>
        <input type="url" name="image" class="form-control" id="image" autofocus>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Category: </label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="category">

            <option>clothing</option>
            <option>electronics</option>
            <option>collectables</option>
            <option>appliances</option>
            <option>furniture</option>
            <option>other</option>
            
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <!--
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="starting_bid">Starting Bid: </label>
        <input type="number" id="starting_bid" name="starting_bid" class="form-control" autofocus>
    </div>
    -->
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description: </label>

        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" rows="6" autofocus required>
        </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>


</form>
```

I've commented out the starting bid everywhere it was mentioned because I was also having problems with that, but I'm not really worried about that for right now, for now I just want to be able to create a listing or two.

I've already run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

This error happens with each of my 4 users, all with an auto incrementing id.

I can print out the users and their id's just fine.

I also get this warning:

```
auctions.Listings.user: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on 
a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.   
        HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.
```

But I still get the same error when using a one to one field or a many to one field. Ultimately I would like for each user to have many listings, but for right now, I'm just trying to get at least one listing created successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This is not needed:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request, "auctions/new_listing.html", {
                "message": "Try logging in first"
            })
```

It could also be the problem.
Try this:

```
@login_required
```

EDIT:
I think that here's the problem.
You have set as a primary key a foreign key. You should erase that "primary_key=True" and django will create one itself.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying, but neither of those work. This still results in the same error.

Comment: Have you specified /new route in urls.py?

Comment: yes, I had, but now I've started over. I had written so little, it seemed like starting over would be best.

Comment: don't I do not recommend it

Comment: lol too late, I did start over and I've already finished it. However, now I'm pretty sure I didn't have to start over, I think I could've just deleted the last migration and rewrote the model, But either way this was a really great learning experience. I only really had problems when I tried to use foreign key for User. I ended up just using a CharField and username since usernames had to be unique, and that worked just fine, even if it's not best practice... ( it might be though, I have no idea )

Comment: You're lucky your question did not get downvoted at once!